# Q, method for non-linear mixed effect model using nlme?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, nonlinear

I'm trying to apply non-linear mixed effect model in my data, but it does not work at all.

My code is,

```
library(nlme)
NQ<-nlme(DAT~A1*exp(A2*Dz_Dur)+A3, data= SET.Q, 
         fixed=A1+A2+A3~1,
         random=A1+A2+A3~1|PATNO,
         start=c(A1=0.301, A2=-0.0295, A3=0.5), verbose=TRUE)
```

(Starting values were obtained from non-linear regression test.)

I tried various values in starting vector, but got various error messages.

1. step halving factor reduced below minimum in PNLS step
2. Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1
3. Unable to form Cholesky decomposition: the leading minor of order 1 is not pos.def.
4. LME step: nlminb() did not converge (code = 1). Do increase 'msMaxIter'!

Here is my data (this is not total, I can't find how to upload my full data.)
[image]
I wanna ask what is wrong in code. Or, what is required to proceed non-linear mixed effect model.

Comment: Non-linear mixed effects models can be difficult to fit. Maybe try first getting a successful fit with one or two of the random effects (for A1 or/and A3). If these are successful, you'll have new starting values for the complete model. To share your data, do `dput(SET.Q)` in R and copy the output into your question (assuming this is not a very large dataset).

Comment: Thank you, Roland. As you recommended, code using 2 random effects (A2 and A3) provides a fit without error message. I wanna ask 1 more question. result of the fit shows strong correlation between random effect of A2 and A3 (corr = -0.975). Should I remove one more random effect?